# Are there an Infinitude of Proper Integrals like this for General Functions? $\int_a^b p_t \, dt\frac{(b-a) }{(t-a)^2};a,b\in \mathbb{C}.$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

The following experimental evidence seems to indicate the following for the [MRB constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRB_constant) (CMRB). Is it truly valid, and can it be generalized to other sums?

$$g_x=x^{1/x};q_k= \Re(g_k-1)\cos(\pi  k);\text{CMRB}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } q_k$$
$$w:=\frac{i (t-b)}{t-a};$$
$$p_t:=\Re g (w+1) \csc(\pi  w)  $$
$$\text{CMRB}=\int_a^b p_t \, dt\frac{(b-a) }{(t-a)^2};a,b\in \mathbb{C}.$$

If my latex is not quite right, here is how it appears in Mathematica.

[image]

I checked it with a full sample range $a,b\in \mathbb{C},$ of code snippets like the following, but I would like to have proof to show for it. (The proof would be useful [here](https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/214522-Formulas-For-The-MRB-Constant).

```
g[x_] = x^(1/x); CMRB = NSum[(-1)^k (g[k] - 1), {k, 1, Infinity}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 100, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"];



g[x_] = x^(1/x); Table[w = (I (t - b))/(t - a);
 CMRB - NIntegrate[
   Re[g[(1 + w)] Csc[\[Pi] w]] (t - a)^-2*(b - a), {t, a, b}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 100], {a, 0, 5}, {b, a + 1, 6}]
```

gives

{{-9.3472*10^-94,...}}[0 to the desired precision].

```
g[x_] = x^(1/x); CMRB = NSum[(-1)^k (g[k] - 1), {k, 1, Infinity}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 100, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"];a = 1; b = I; g[x_] = x^(1/x); (w = (I (t - b))/(t - a);
 Print[CMRB - 
   NIntegrate[
    Re[g[(1 + w)] Csc[\[Pi] w]] (t - a)^-2*(b - a), {t, a, b}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 100]]); Clear[a, b]
```

gives
-9.3472*10^-94+0.*10^-189 I [0 to the desired precision].

Even complex transcendental limits work!

```
g[x_] = x^(1/x); CMRB = NSum[(-1)^k (g[k] - 1), {k, 1, Infinity}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 100, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"];

a = E + Pi I; b = Pi - E I; g[x_] = x^(1/x); (w = (I (t - b))/(t - a);
 Print[CMRB - 
   NIntegrate[
    Re[g[(1 + w)] Csc[\[Pi] w]] (t - a)^-2*(b - a), {t, a, b}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 100]]); Clear[a, b]
```

gives
-9.3472*10^-94+0.*10^-107 I [0 to the desired precision].

Comment: Hope this helps:  started out changing the bounds from 1 to infinity, to 0 to 1 like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360675/transformation-of-integral-from-0-to-infinity-to-0-to-1 . Then reasoned what a and b should be for the other integrals,

Comment: When I see a tiny number like this on Mathematica, I immediately think it's zero and the result is just due to numerical imprecision. I haven't looked into this further but perhaps the constant is just zero.

Comment: @integrand, yes I think they are zero, meaning $$\text{CMRB}=\int_a^b \frac{(b-a) }{(t-a)^2}p_t \, dt,a,b\in \mathbb{C}.
$$